# Policyd quotas setup

Tags: postfix, quota

I have installed and configured policyd 2.0.8 according to INSTALL document in installation directory. My webui works fine, no problem reported in logs.

And then I setup some quotas on Default policy.
Quota:
 - Policy: Default
 - Name: Sending quota
 - Track: SenderIP:/24
 - Period: 3600
 - Verdict: REJECT
 - Data:
 - Disabled: no
Limits:
 - Type: Message count
 - Counter limit: 2
 - Disabled: no

But, problem is that I'm still able to send as manu messages as I want. Perhaps I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell your mail server to check the policyd?

Answer (score 0):

I did. But never mind, I left policyd

Comment: Can you share what you're using now ?